# Opencart logged users see products without taxes

Tags: opencart2.x

I have enabled taxes for default customer group. I user is not logged opencart displays products prices with taxes, when customer log to account products prices are displayed without prices. Where can be problem ?

I have only 1 zone/ country.

Comment: will u modify ur question plz, it's hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart Tax works on current customer customer group. Like you are saying you enable tax for default customer group. So when a customer is not login means, customer is guest, Opencart set default customer group to that customer.

```
    //code in your index.php where OC set customer groups for current customer  
    // Customer Group
    if ($customer->isLogged()) {
        $config->set('config_customer_group_id', $customer->getGroupId());
    } elseif (isset($session->data['customer']) && isset($session->data['customer']['customer_group_id'])) {
        // For API calls
        $config->set('config_customer_group_id', $session->data['customer']['customer_group_id']);
    } elseif (isset($session->data['guest']) && isset($session->data['guest']['customer_group_id'])) {
        $config->set('config_customer_group_id', $session->data['guest']['customer_group_id']);
    }
```

so when customer is not login then price is displaying with taxes and when login then price is showing without taxes - **Reason must be that your login customer has customer group other than default one**.
You can check customer group after edit customer from admin side.